# Count duplicate rows with constraint

Tags: bash, awk, perl

I have the following file:

```
A B 1990
A C 2001
A C 2013
A B 2001
B C 2013
A D 2001
A D 2014
```

I need to count duplicate pairs (in the 1st and 2nd column) and to each such pair assign the lowest value from the 3rd column. For my toy file the output should be:

```
A B 2 1990
A C 2 2001
A D 2 2001
B C 1 2013
```

For example, pair `A B` occurs two times, first time with value 1990 and second time with value 2001, because 1990 < 2001 we assign 1990 to this count.

I wonder how to do that with Linux tools (Bash, AWK, Perl). Any ideas / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for `awk`.

Comment: @HalosGhost Any idea how to start?

Comment: It seems that students in masses post questions here =)

Comment: I this your homework?

Comment: No, I parse MEDLINE and this is only a small (but nasty) detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -v SUBSEP=" " '
    {a[$1,$2]++;b[$1,$2] = (b[$1,$2] && $3 > b[$1,$2]) ? b[$1,$2] : $3}
    END {
        for (i in a) {
            print i,a[i],b[i];
        }
    }
' file
A B 2 1990
A C 2 2001
A D 2 2001
B C 1 2013
```

Even shorter if you can change the order of field:

```
$ sort -n -k1 -k2 -k3 file | uniq -c -w 3
      2 A B 1990
      2 A C 2001
      2 A D 2001
      1 B C 2013
```

Comment: Is there `-k4` or `-k3` in the last one-liner?

Comment: @Andrej: `-k3`, mistypo, fixed.

Comment: I get "Segmentation fault" when execute your awk expression on 1.2 GB file. Any idea why?

Comment: @Andrej: the `awk` solution stored all things in memory, so it can crash while process huge file, because of not enough memory.